# Sum of the elements ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I'm a beginner in Java and trying to get the sum of all the elements in the ArrayList. I'm doing it by using a method and get this error in the method:

> "bad operand types for binary operator '+' first type: int, second
> type: Object"

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, appreciate any help!

```
public static int sumNumbers(<ArrayList> numbers){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
        sum+=numbers.get(i);
   }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList numbers` should be `ArrayList<Integer> numbers`, the type is missing.

Comment: `ArrayList` only is basically the same as `ArrayList<Object>` (not entirely but in the context of your question you can think of it that way). Hence in `sum+=numbers.get(i);` the compiler sees the operation as `int = int + Object`. If you change that to `ArrayList<Integer>` (or better `List<Integer>`) the compiler will see `int = int + Integer` and can apply auto-unboxing to get `int = int + int`.

Comment: Or you have to explicitly cast it to int

Comment: @NicholasK you can't _cast_ an `Integer` object to `int`, you'd need to unbox it, e.g. via `Integer.intValue()` or letting the compiler do that for you.

Comment: You can cast it and then call `.intValue()`

Comment: @NicholasK you can cast to `Integer` but _not_ `int`. In the first case you'd not need the explicit call to `intValue()` (unless you're working on Java 1.4 or less).

Comment: @Thomas you can't ? `jshell` and eclipse have no problem with it. (`Object a = new Integer(123);
        int b = (int) a;`) - not saying it should be done that way

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger hmm, seems as if the compiler is cleverer as I thought, although it technically would be a combination of casting to `Integer` and then unboxing the value and I'd not trust the compiler to be able to do that in all circumstances.

Comment: @Camilla or change the type of the list, as suggested by some answers; or use `sum += (Integer) numbers.get(i);` (despite first is more indicated)

Comment: Thank you all! It works fine now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `numbers` as `ArrayList<Integer> numbers`.
Then the `Integer` will be unboxed to `int`. Right now, your `arraylist` contains `objects` that may not be `int`s.

For the moment, `numbers.get()` will return an `object`, and you can not add an `object` to an `int` directly.

You could always cast the element to `Integer`, but I would recommend the first option.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you need to give your `ArrayList` a type. You can then use native streams to make the code a little more compact:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = ... ;
numbers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a list
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

// get the sum of the elements in the list
int sum = MathUtils.sum(ints);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will works fine.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static int sumNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> numbers){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
      sum+=numbers.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Or

```
public static int sumNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> numbers){
    return numbers.stream().mapToInt(n->n).sum();
  }
```