# Sum of an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, sum, average

I'm trying to make an average (moy) of an arrayList's column but I need to sum it first, I don't know how to do it

```
    int sumX = 0;
    val = new ArrayList<>();
    float moy[] = new float[3];

          if (i < 100) {
                    val.add(sensorEvent.values);
                i++;
            } else {
                for (; i > 0; i--);
                {
                    sumX = ?
                    moy[0] = sumX/100;
                }
                val.clear();
                i = 0;
}
```

Comment: this `float moy[] new float[3];` is not a valid syntax. And why would the average of an array be an array?

Comment: we have no idea what type is in the list, nor what is `sensorEvent.values`, neither what is "arrayList's column" - better include the correct declaration of variables (and some hints what the data is)

Comment: @jhamon sorry, forgot the "=" . Actually, I'm trying to make an average of the values (float) I'm getting from the accelerometer. So there are 3 "columns" in my ArraList , (x, y, z). I'm just trying to get the average of x for now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of the elements ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874037/sum-of-the-elements-arraylist)

Comment: I think @CarlosHeuberger question is about the type of `sensorEvent.values` (array of ...? List of ... ?, Object?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code snippet: (Written in kotlin)

```
fun main() {
val s: List<Float> = listOf(1.2F, 1.4F, 5.6F) 
// populate it with your custom list data
var sum = 0F

s.forEach { it ->
    sum+=it
}
println("Sum = $sum and avg = ${sum/(s.size)}")

}
```

Well here is the java solution:

```
class Ideone
{
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {
    List<Float> s = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1.2F, 1.3F, 5.4F, 6.5F));
    Float sum = 0F;
    
    for (int i=0; i< s.size(); i++) {
        sum+=s.get(i);
    }
    
System.out.println("Sum: "+sum+" and Avg: "+sum/(s.size()));
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html):

Variants:

1. The input is an array of `double`

   `double[] values = new double[] {1.1D, 2.33D, 4D};
    double average = DoubleStream.of(values).average().getAsDouble();`
2. The input is an `ArrayList` of `Integer`

   `ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(1); 
    values.add(42);
    values.add(-1);

    double average = values.stream().mapToDouble(value -> (double) value).average().getAsDouble();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to sum all values in an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
// Populate ArrayList
int sum = 0;
for (int num : nums) {
    sum += num;
}
// Do whatever you want with sum after
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use averaging collector in streams and you don't have to calculate **SUM** and **NUMBER** of elements:

```
ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>() {{
  add(1d);
  add(2.45d);
  add(100d);
}};

final double average = numbers.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(d -> d));

moy[0] = average;
```